# Alternative to except in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I must write a Query like this in MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tab1
EXCEPT
SELECT * 
FROM Tab1 
WHERE int_attribute_of_Tab1>0
```

but MySQL doesn't support the keyword **EXCEPT**. 
Is there a *standard mode* to use correctly another operator that simulate the except in MySQL?

Comment: Surely SELECT * 
FROM Tab1 
WHERE int_attribute_of_Tab1 = 0 would do? Or should tab1 in second select be tab2?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could use NOT IN

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tab1
WHERE id  NOT IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM Tab1 
    WHERE int_attribute_of_Tab1>0
)
```

Comment: seems not to work if I have two columns:
`select distinct col1, col2 from Tab1
where col1, col2 not in(select distinct col1, col2 from Tab2)`
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @MrZH6 in case you're still wondering, you can't select multiple columns in a subquery as it must be compared to a single column from the main query (here `col2`). But you can select multiple columns in other subqueries like with derived tables.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tab1
WHERE [....] NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * 
FROM Tab1 
WHERE int_attribute_of_Tab1>0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple `NOT IN` operators combined with `AND` operators for multiple columns.
For example:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE col1 NOT IN(SELECT col1 FROM table2) AND col2 NOT IN(SELECT col2 FROM table2)...;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [MySQL version 8.0.31 update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-31.html), the [`EXCEPT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/except.html) operator has become available to use in this DBMS. If you are allowed to update your MySQL version, you are free to use the notation:

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Tab1 
WHERE int_attribute_of_Tab1>0
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of definitions 
SqlServer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql EXCEPT
Returns any distinct values from the query to the left of the EXCEPT operator that are not also returned from the right query.
PLsql https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm MINUS 
statement combines results with the MINUS operator, which returns only unique rows returned by the first query but not by the second

A pedantic translation to mysql would be

```
 SELECT distinct t1.* 
FROM Tab1 as t1
left outer join
(SELECT * 
FROM Tab1 
WHERE int_attribute_of_Tab1>0) as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null;
```

Assuming there is an id column, And I wouldn't like to use distinct on a lot of columns.

Comment: Even SQLite supports EXCEPT, bad luck.

Answer (score 0):

If Tab1 has a primary key (f.e. ID) then you could use a `NOT EXISTS` to itself like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tab1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Tab1 AS t2
    WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
      AND t2.int_attribute_of_Tab1 > 0
)
```

But it's kinda pointless in this case.
And it's not what an EXCEPT/MINUS tries to do.
(excluding identical rows)

The question's query with the `EXCEPT` uses the same table twice.
So reversing that `WHERE` criteria on Tab1 would give the same results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tab1 
WHERE (int_attribute_of_Tab1 <= 0 OR int_attribute_of_Tab1 IS NULL)
```

If it were 2 different tables then this

```
SELECT t1col1, t1col2, t1col3
FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT t2col4, t2col5, t2col6
FROM Table2
WHERE int_attribute_of_Tab1 > 0
```

Could be replaced by comparing each selected column

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1col1, t1col2, t1col3
FROM Table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Table1 AS t2
    WHERE t2.t2col4 = t1.t1col1
      AND t2.t2col5 = t1.t1col2
      AND t2.t2col6 = t1.t1col3
      AND t2.int_attribute_of_Tab1 > 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this solution but it takes into consideration all the fields and wont be a simple select *.

Suppose you have field id,name, att1, att2, fin_year in one table tbl_tab
which has 50 records of fin_year =2022 and 25 record of fin_year =2023

Now to get all the data from tab1 for fin_year 2022 except fin_year 20233
the following needs to be done.

```
select * from tbl_tab 
where fin_year=2022 and id not in (
select t1.id 
from tbl_tab t1 
inner join tbl_tab t2 
   on t2.name=t1.name
   and t2.att1=t1.att1
   and t2.att2=t1.att2
where t1.fin_year=2022
and t2.fin_year=2023);
```

This is equivalent of

```
select name, att1, att2, fin_year from tbl_tab where fin_year=2022
except 
select name , att1, att2, fin_year from tbl_tab where fin_year=2023;
```