# Union of Three tables without any duplicates minus one table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, join, union

Table:2018

```
No  Email

1   Lilly@gmail.com

2   brens@gmail.com

3   susan@gmail.com

4   resh@gmail.com
```

Table:2017

```
No   Email

1    chitta@gmail.com

2    resh@gmail.com

3    brens@gmail.com

4    minu@gmail.com
```

Table:2016

```
No   Email

1     brens@gmail.com

2     chitta@gmail.com

3     lisa@gmail.com

4     monay@gmail.com

5     many@gmail.com
```

Table:2019

```
No   Email

1    brens@gmail.com

2    chitta@gmail.com

3    rinu@gmail.com

4    emma@gmail.com
```

I need to perform Union of tables 2018,2017,2016 without any duplicate emails minus table 2019 ,Result should look like

RESULT

```
No  Email

1    Lilly@gmail.com

2    susan@gmail.com

3    resh@gmail.com

4    minu@gmail.com

5   lisa@gmail.com

6   monay@gmail.com

7   many@gmail.com
```

Minus operation is not available in Mysql.

```
select a.*from(select *from y2018 union select *from y2017 where not exists(select *from y2018 where y2018.email=y2017.email ) union select *from y2016 where not exists(select *from y2018 where y2018.email=y2016.email ))a LEFT OUTER JOIN y2019 b on a.email=b.email  where b.email is null ;
```

This gives the result but does not eliminate the duplicates in (2017 union 2016)

some one please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to except in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872015/alternative-to-except-in-mysql)

Comment: Why is `resh@gmail.com` in the expected results?

Comment: @RaymondNijland (2018 UNION 2017 UNION 2016) resh@gmail.com is in table 2017

Comment: That still does not explain it but i got the point when i readed *"I need to perform Union of tables 2018,2017,2016 without any duplicate emails minus table 2019"*

Comment: i hope you are also aware that the No column in the expected results does not relate to your real data annymore?  And needs to be generated?

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes No column needs to be generated . I am pretty new to this i tried different queries but failing

Comment: *"I am pretty new to this i tried different queries but failing"*  Check mine answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a better method, creating a view and save a portion of the query in it. It helps to reduce the processing time as well.

```
create view vm as select *from y2018 union select *from y2017 where not exists(select *from y2018 where y2018.email=y2017.email);

SELECT  a.*FROM(SELECT * FROM vm union select *from y2016 where not exists(select *from vm where vm.email=y2016.email))a LEFT JOIN y2019 b ON a.email=b.email where b.email is null;
```

Here 'vm' is the view

Answer (score 0):

> I need to perform Union of tables 2018,2017,2016 without any duplicate
>   emails minus table 2019

The most easy to simulate/emulate minus/expect is using `NOT IN()`

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   (@ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1) AS 'No' 
 , unique_email.Email
FROM (

  SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
      years_merged.Email  
  FROM (

    SELECT 
     Email
    FROM 
     y2019
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
     Email
    FROM 
     y2018
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
     Email
    FROM
     y2017   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
     Email
    FROM 
     y2016     

  ) AS years_merged
  WHERE 
   years_merged.Email NOT IN(SELECT y2019.Email FROM y2019 ) 
  ORDER BY
   years_merged.Email ASC
) AS unique_email
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 0) AS init
ORDER BY 
  @ROW_NUMBER ASC
```

**Result**

```
| No  | Email           |
| --- | --------------- |
| 1   | Lilly@gmail.com |
| 2   | lisa@gmail.com  |
| 3   | many@gmail.com  |
| 4   | minu@gmail.com  |
| 5   | monay@gmail.com |
| 6   | resh@gmail.com  |
| 7   | susan@gmail.com |
```

Yes the order is different but this is the best you can do as SQL standards defines SQL tables to be sorted orderless..

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYKfSrgfn5jbxC1StDtm5V/2)

But a simulate/emulate minus/expect using `... LEFT JOIN ... ON ... WHERE .. IS NULL` might optimize better vs a `NOT IN()`

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYKfSrgfn5jbxC1StDtm5V/4)

Comment: Thanks very much , i really appreciate your help.. Just one more thing what if another columns are present in the table,something like name and address and need to display all the fields

Comment: *"Just one more thing what if another columns are present in the table,something like name and address and need to display all the fields"* @NeenaSusan that will involve a other writing method one of the "problems" is that MySQL does not support `DISTINCT ON(email), *` (PostgreSQL) syntax otherwise it would be very simple but you can [simulate/emulate (post of mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868870/how-to-use-distinct-on-with-mysql-using-activerecord/53869691#53869691) it..

Comment: is there anyway to use 'group by' in the same query instead of distinct

Comment: *"is there anyway to use 'group by' in the same query instead of distinct "*  Yes but `GROUP BY` is not really designed to unduplicate and ideally you should only use `GROUP BY` when you are going to use [Aggregate (GROUP BY) Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) also in the query

Comment: i understood. Could you please show me the other way