# How to use EXCEPT in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

How to use EXCEPT in Laravel 8

```
SELECT Customers.id,Customers.fullname
FROM Customers
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.id,Customers.fullname
FROM orders
JOIN Customers
ON Customers.id=orders.Customers_id
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support except, so just use `not exists` or `not in`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative to except in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872015/alternative-to-except-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not support EXCEPT. Use

```sql
SELECT Customers.id,Customers.fullname
FROM Customers
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM orders
                   WHERE Customers.id=orders.Customers_id )
```

---

> how to use in laravel ? – Khaled

If you don't know how to use correlated subquery in Laravel (I don't know - I don't use Laravel) - try

```sql
SELECT Customers.id,Customers.fullname
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN orders ON Customers.id=orders.Customers_id
WHERE orders.Customers_id IS NULL
```

Comment: how to use in laravel ?

Answer (score 1):

I need to do in Laravel 8

```sql
SELECT Customers.id,Customers.fullname
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN orders ON Customers.id=orders.Customers_id
WHERE orders.Customers_id IS NULL
```