# SQL function to count the number of times a customer logged in

Tags: sql

With this formula, it shows the number of log times perfectly, since day 1:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(time) AS session_count 
FROM login_history
GROUP BY username;
```

But with this one, which is my (almost) full formula to gather a lot of different data, it doesn't give me the same results regarding the logs count:

```
SELECT 
    user.username AS 'Contact ID', 
    user.firstname AS 'First name', 
    user.lastname AS 'Last name', 
    user.email AS Email, 
    user.orgname AS 'Company ID', 
    expiry_date AS 'Expiry date', 
    COUNT(time) AS 'Login activity since day 1', 
    MAX(time) AS 'Last login date',  
    login_history.browser_family AS 'Web browser', 
    login_history.browser_version AS 'Web browser version', 
    login_history.os_family AS 'Device OS', 
    login_history.os_version AS 'OS version', 
    login_history.device_family AS 'Device family', 
    login_history.device_brand AS 'Device brand', 
    login_history.device_model AS 'Device model', 
    login_history.ip_address AS 'IP address', 
    RIGHT(user.email, length(user.email)-INSTR(user.email, '@')) AS 'Company domain'
FROM 
    `user`
INNER JOIN 
    `login_history` ON login_history.username = user.username 
WHERE 
    orgname != 'XXX'
    AND is_active = 1
GROUP BY 
    user.username, user.firstname, user.lastname, user.email, 
    user.orgname, login_history.browser_family, 
    login_history.browser_version, login_history.os_family, 
    login_history.os_version, login_history.device_family, 
    login_history.device_brand, login_history.device_model, 
    login_history.ip_address
ORDER BY 
    orgname ASC;
```

I'm also trying to complete this formula to gather session logs count from the past 30 days and also from the past 3 days...

Thanks a lot for your help! :D

Comment: It's good programming practice to qualify all columns (at least when several tables are involved.) E.g. `user.orgname` instead of just `expiry_date`.

Comment: this is i think usually caused by outer join issues - like maybe not all users have email addresses or something.

Answer (score 0):

Without data is not easy to try to guide you, but I would do as follows. Let's call `"user_stuff"` the whole `user.username, user.firstname, user.lastname, user.email, user.orgname` and `login_stuff` the whole `login_history.browser_family, login_history.browser_version, login_history.os_family, login_history.os_version, login_history.device_family, login_history.device_brand, login_history.device_model, login_history.ip_address`.

Does the following work as intended?

```
SELECT "login_stuff", COUNT(time) AS session_count 
FROM login_history
GROUP BY "login_stuff";
```

If so, does the following work as intended?

```
SELECT "login_stuff", COUNT(time) AS session_count 
FROM login_history
WHERE orgname != 'XXX' AND is_active = 1
GROUP BY "login_stuff";
```

If so, does the full query work as intended? Knowing where you introduced the "bug" (maybe just assumptions about the data) is of vital importance to try to understand how to fix this problem.

Comment: The conditions in the WHERE are in the table 'user_stuff' so I can't add it with the 'login_stuff' without a JOIN.

Comment: The first query works well and seems to provide more accurate results. That's why I don't understand it doesn't work in the FULL query...

Comment: Ok it seems that the INNER JOIN is the root cause of the different results!

Comment: I'm still learning but I don't really notice a difference for my full query whether I use INNER, LEFT or RIGHT JOIN

Comment: to see what you are missing from one query to another, you can use something like EXCEPT with syntax (bigger query (the LEFT or RIGHT one)) EXCEPT (smaller query (the INNER)) https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 what db are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHPMYADMIN with MYSQL

Comment: By the way, do you know if there's a possibility to add functions about the MAX(time) to get the data from the past 30 days and the past 3 days please?

Comment: you can use HAVING MAX(time) >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) (if you want the last login to be in the last 30 days)  or WHERE time >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) (if you only want the logs of the last 30 days)

Comment: you don't have except in mysql, but you can use NOT IN like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872015/alternative-to-except-in-mysql

Comment: I mean, getting from day 1, the past 30 days AND the past 3 days ; all in the same query. Is that possible? Thanks a lot by the way!

Comment: Yes: you can do something like SELECT common_stuff, subquery3.time3, subquery30.time30 FROM tables LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(time) as time3 WHERE...) as subquery3 on subquery3.id = tables.id LEFT JOIN (analogous for 30 days)

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get it... Why are there 2 LEFT JOIN and a WHERE in the middle?

Comment: because this syntax will join subqueries that might be empty

Comment: I'm still working on it, thanks! By the way, I understand why I had different results with or without the INNER JOIN: now my results are separated by IP address so it filters the quantities and also I setup a WHERE condition to disregard my company employees data